# How to return custom component from another function in react JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, custom-component

This is my `first.js` file

```
import Second from "./second";

function ClickHandler() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Second></Second>
      </div>
    );
 }


function First() {

  return (
    <div>
      <div>This is first</div>

      <div>
        <button onClick={ClickHandler}>Click it</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default First;
```

This is my `second.js` file

```
function Second(){
    return(
        <div>
            <div>
                This is Second
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Second;
```

I want to disply the content of `second.js` file when button gets clicked. But this is not working as expected?
Any solution for this?
Please...

Comment: do you want to toggle between first  and second components?

Comment: You cannot return a JSX element from an event listener. You can store the display status of the element in state and toggle the element accordingly.  I suggest you to re-visit React concepts.

Comment: @varaprasadh
I want to display 'this is second' in the screen when the button gets clicked

Comment: @HanMoeHtet
Can you please elaborate

Comment: within the first component or as stand alone component?

Comment: @varaprasadh
As a stand alone one

Comment: onClick => setState shouldShowSecondComponent to true and in jsx you can do shouldShowSecondComponent && <secondComponent/>

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Second from "./second";



function First() {
 const [secondComponentVisibility, setSecondComponentVisibility] = 
 useState(false);

  const ClickHandler = () => {
    setSecondComponentVisibility(true)
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div>This is first</div>

      <div>
        <button onClick={ClickHandler}>Click it</button>
      </div>

      {secondComponentVisibility && <Second/>}
    </div>
  );
}
export default First;
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function First() {
   const [showSecond, setShowsecond] = useState(false);
  return (
   showSecond ? <SecondComponent/> : <div>
      <div>This is first</div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={()=>setShowsecond(true)}>Click it</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default First;
```

hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

`first.js`

```js
import React, { useState } from react

import Second from './second'

function First() {
    const [IsSecondShowing, SetIsSecondShowing] = useState(false)

    return (
        <div>
            <div>This is first</div>
            {IsSecondShowing ? <Second /> : null}
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => SetIsSecondShowing(prev => !prev)}>
                    Click it
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default First
```

`second.js`

```js
import React from 'react'

function Second() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>This is Second</div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Second
```